# How to find percentage of people belonging to atleast 2 groups in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I just started using R. And I have a stata dataset which I opened in R. In the questionnaire there is a question “Please  look  carefully  at  the  following  list  of  political groups and  say  which,  if any, do you belong to?” . Variable v1 to v10 represents the different groups and each have values of 1 or 0 which is ‘yes’ or ‘no’.
My question is: How do I find the percentage of people who are members of atleast 2 groups?

I think I’m supposed to use dplyr but I am not sure.

One of the idea that I've got was to use filter and mutate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> stat <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v2 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v3 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v4 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v5 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v6 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v7 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v8 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v9 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
+                    v10 = sample(c(0,1), 10, T), stringsAsFactors = F)
> stat
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
1   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
2   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
3   0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
4   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
5   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   0
6   0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
7   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
8   0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   1
9   0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
10  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
> stat %>% mutate(groups_member = rowSums(.)) %>% mutate(atleast_two_groups = case_when(groups_member >= 2 ~ 'Yes', TRUE ~ 'No')) %>% select(-groups_member)
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 atleast_two_groups
1   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   1                Yes
2   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1                Yes
3   0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0                Yes
4   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0                Yes
5   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   0                Yes
6   0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   0                Yes
7   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1                Yes
8   0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   1                Yes
9   0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1                Yes
10  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1                Yes
>
```

So the dataframe is like a matrix with 10 variables each having either 0 or 1. So creating a new column that sums up all rows and if the total count is more than 2 which is more than atleast 20% (2/10) then it tells whether it satisfies your query.

Comment: If v1 to v10 is in form of character, do I need to change it first before doing this?

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example using dput(dataframe_name) so that I can see what the data looks like

Comment: v9                 : dbl+lbl [1:56368] 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,...
   ..@ label       : chr "do you belong to: religious organization (Q4A)"
   ..@ format.stata: chr "%8.0g"
   ..@ labels      : Named num [1:12] -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ...
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "multiple answers Mail" "no follow-up" "follow-up non response" "matrix not applied" ...
 
   .

Comment: I used mutate instead: EVS2018 <- mutate(EVS2018,
                  members = v9 + v10 + v11 + v12 + v13 + v14 + v15 + v16 + v17 + v18 + v19)

Comment: > with(stat, v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6 + v7 + v8 + v9 + v10)
 [1] 7 6 5 4 5 7 3 5 3 4, but I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish? Are you looking for something else apart from what I answered?

Comment: so I just added the variables together and creates another variable with the results. and then filter it with the criteria the question was asking for. I got the idea from looking at your answer. And I think it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column, where you add up all 1's and 0' then sum up the values that are greater or smaller than 2.

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- matrix(ifelse(runif(100)>=0.1,0,1),10,10) %>% 
  as_tibble(,.name_repair = "unique")


dat %>% 
  mutate(rsum = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  summarise(fewer_than_two = 100*sum(rsum<2)/n(),
            more_than_two = 100*sum(rsum>=2)/n())

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  fewer_than_two more_than_two
           <dbl>         <dbl>
1             80            20
```

Answer (score 0):

Start creating some fake data

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(id = 1:5,
             v1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
             v2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
             v3 = rep(0, 5),
             v4 = rep(0, 5),
             v5 = rep(0, 5),
             v6 = rep(0, 5),
             v7 = rep(0, 5),
             v8 = rep(0, 5),
             v9 = rep(0, 5),
             v10 = rep(0, 5))
```

This is our table. Note that out of 5 observations we have 2 people (40%) who are members of at least 2 groups

```
> df
  # A tibble: 5 x 11
  id    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9   v10
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5     5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

First, I calculate the sum of the variables 1 to 10, creating a variable that gets true if greater than or equal to 2 and false otherwise. Then we group by this new variable and calculate the percentages

```
result <- df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(two_or_more = sum(c_across(v1:v10)) >= 2) %>%
   group_by(two_or_more) %>%
   summarize(percentage = sum(n()) / nrow(df) * 100)
```

The result should look like this

```
> result
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  two_or_more percentage
  <lgl>            <dbl>
1 FALSE               60
2 TRUE                40
```